# Microsoft VS2015 C++ Core Guidelines Analysis: "no array to pointer decay (bounds.3)" for vtable?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, cpp-core-guidelines

When I run the CppCoreCheck code analysis on my VS2015 project, I get a number of warnings which seem "unfixable" because they refer to the underlying C++ implementation of classes and vtables:

An example class:

```
// Header file
class IMyClass {
public:
    virtual ~IMyClass() {}
    virtual void MyMethod() = 0;
};

class MyClass : public virtual IMyClass {
public:
    MyClass();
    virtual ~MyClass();
    virtual void MyMethod() override;
};


// Impl file
MyClass::MyClass() { } // This line creates two warnings from CppCoreCheck
MyClass::~MyClass() { }
void MyClass::MyMethod() { }
```

And the warnings:

```
warning C26485: Expression 'MyClass::`vbtable'': No array to pointer decay. (bounds.3: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=620415)
warning C26481: Don't use pointer arithmetic. Use span instead. (bounds.1: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=620413)
```

The line which the warning is complaining about references the constructor definition for `MyClass`

For clarity; I am not directly referencing the vtable anywhere in my code; I'm simply using virtual inheritance in a 100% typical fashion.

Can someone confirm if this is a bug specific to VS2015's implementation of the CppCoreCheck?  If so, is it resolved in VS2017?

Comment: Can you provide a small code example where this occurs ?

Comment: Certainly; apologies.  I've updated the question with a complete code snippet.

Comment: See: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/60755/c-core-check-c26485-and-c26481-warning-in-construc.html   _"...fixed in: visual studio 2017 version 15.5..."_

Comment: Pasting your code into VS2017, I didnt get the warning message.

Comment: That's too bad it can't be addressed in the CppCoreChecker NuGet package.  My company hasn't updated to VS2017 yet, but we'll live with the extra warnings for now.

Feel free to add this as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in VS2015 which will not be fixed.  It is [resolved as of VS2017, v15.5](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/60755/c-core-check-c26485-and-c26481-warning-in-construc.html).